# Server giving http 400 error after WebSocket handshake request

Tags: c, websocket, jetty, http-status-code-400, cometd

I'am trying to achieve an open source CometD library in C, to be able to run a CometD client on barely any given device.

The Long_Polling technique to handshake and communicate with the server is done, so logically i have to give the WebSocket option to the user.

So i fetched the Inter Web and bumped into the [NoPoll](http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/html/group__nopoll__conn_ga0b31b7e0694d654663b49ecaf82c0776.html#ga0b31b7e0694d654663b49ecaf82c0776) library to help me out on the WebSocket part.

Thanks to [NoPoll](http://www.aspl.es/nopoll/html/group__nopoll__conn_ga0b31b7e0694d654663b49ecaf82c0776.html#ga0b31b7e0694d654663b49ecaf82c0776) now i can reach the server and knock on his door, but when i try to handshake with it i always get this 400 Error :

Here is my Handshake :

```
GET ws://m.zpush.ovh:8080/str/strd HTTP/1.1
Host: m.zpush.ovh:8080
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Extension: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Z0WLawAAAADGI3syAAAAAA==
Origin: null
Cookie: BAYEUX_BROWSER=56a9-mchhnynonz6ji8a6hs1sh49; JSESSIONID=8gz8e00htqrl15vcm3o9yi95f
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

And here is the Jetty error :

```
WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp1213415012-14: badMessage: 400 for HttpChannelOverHttp@40ec53c2{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

So i fetched again the cybernet but i didn't found any clue about it. 
From i what i read jetty usually gives more precise error messages, but you will agree this one is very blurry.

It doesn't tell my why and what should i fix to achieve the Handshake. But i suspect that i'am missing something in the HandShake Format.

The other thing that i doesn't understand is that it says "HttpParser" but i'am looking for a WebSocket Handshake.

Any light on this would be much appreciated, and as always when i get an answer i properly make a little tutorial using the given answer to help others developers and give them some code to stand on.

PS : I can upload my code on GitHub if it is needed no problem.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely you have a misconfigured server, without support for WebSocket.

I suggest that you start the CometD demo server like explained [here](http://docs.cometd.org/3/reference/#_installation_demos), and try your C client against that.

I just tried your upgrade request (just replaced the host name and port), and it works just fine.

Comment: As always thank you for your fast answers. Concerning the misconfiguration of the server i can totally be true, but i have a doubt about it as it works well with Java and JavaScript, is there a difference with a request coming from a C client ? As i send my Handshake by Tcp protocol and not http. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tested your upgrade via TCP by using telnet, and you can only send HTTP requests via TCP, so the language is not an issue, if you do it right.